# How to recognize that integer value is thousands, hundreds, or tens?

Tags: javascript, function, integer

I have several numbers to proceed, let's assume that my numbers are :
14000,32100,510,2100, and 10000
So, how to make the numbers recognized as thousands or hundreds in javascript?
Is there any function for this?

Comment: What does "recognized as thousands" mean?

Comment: It means: if the number is `5100` the function for recognizing this will return "thousands", and so if `300` it will return "hundreds"

Comment: Uhh, what about simple numeric comparisons `if (num >= 1000)` for thousands followed by `else if (num >= 100)` for hundreds.

Answer (score 8):

Use a logarithm. A base 10 log if available, or make a base 10 log from a natural log (ln) via ln(n)/ln(10).  Like so:

```
var log10=function(n){return Math.log(n)/Math.log(10);};
log10(100);    //2
log10(10000);  //4
log10(1000000);//6, uh actually 5.999999999999999
```

Might need to round the result due to lack of precision. Rounded version:

```
function log10(n){
  return Math.round(100*Math.log(n)/Math.log(10))/100;
}
[10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000].map(log10);

/*
1,2,3,4,5,6
*/
```

Also you should cache the Math.log(10) result if performance is an issue;

Comment: please vote to close this question, i think the question doesn't look like what i am looking for

Comment: What's the point of using two log operations when you can just compare to see if the number is greater or less than some trigger value?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, come to think of it, it'll probably end up taking much more code and `if` statements to actually get a "hundred", "thousands", "millions" type of result.  I just felt logarithms would be more elegant.  You could (like you said) just test actual numbers like 100, 1000.  Or even attempt to count digits in string representation (although I think that's just asking for trouble).  It's just one of a few ways to approach the problem.

Comment: This creates absolutely unnecessary computation. You can just use `String(num).length - 1` to get the number of zeroes

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```
var number = 5300;

function NumberName(number)
{
    switch (number.toString().length)
    {
    case 3:
         return "hundreds";
    case 4:
        return "thousands";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int x = Math.floor(Math.log10(number)) + 1;
```

returns the total number of digits of a number (for 100 returns 3, for 1000 returns 4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a built-in function like that sorry, but if you just have integers you can write your own function for that:

```
function numberDigits(number) {
    return number.toString().length
}
```

Now you can easily dicide if the number is thousands or hundreds etc...

Note that this **only** works with integer values!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your Mark-up looks like :

But for a given markup like below:

```
<div class="save-sale" style="font-size: .8em; padding-top: 4em">10000</div>
```

You can use something like:

```
$(function () {
$(".save-sale").click(function (i) {
   var a = $.trim($(".save-sale").text()).length;
    alert(a);
});
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/721/)

Comment: please vote to close this question, i think the question doesn't look like what i am looking for

Comment: I would have done that, but the solution provided by @jongo45 is quite noticeable. So I would rather chose not to. And BTW you can always edit you question to make it better.

Comment: yes, all of the answers here are the right answer for what the question asked. but, the point is not clear, i posted the wrong question.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi: May be the answers here is not exactly what you are looking for, but some one could find these answers useful soemday. Or the question here is not anything like you wanted to post, but still for the sake of other users I still Insist on not taking down the POST.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, No method exist to identify a number is hundreds or thousands, but you can create your own
ex:

```
function check(num){
         if(num>999) { return 'thousands'; }
         if(num>99) {  return 'hundreds'; }
}
```